# C# Generate Panel Form

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to create an application where I can save multiple blocks of information. (i.e

[image: What my form looks like]

At the bottom of this I want to add a 'Next/New' button that creates a new "form" (or page or panel) with the same fields and at the bottom of this new form/page/panel? I will have a 'Previous' and 'Next/New' button aswell. So I would like to give the user the option to go back and edit or move forward and keep creating more forms.

So my question is, how do I do this? Can I have a button that will generate a form?

At the end of user input I want to save all the information into an excel file.

Comment: What framework are you using?  I suspect as it is this question will be closed as it's too broad.

Comment: Ah sorry, im using C# Visual Studios 2015. Windows Form Application

Comment: That's the language.  Is it Winforms, WPF, ASP.net?

Comment: @DarrenYoung I edited after I typed it, Windows Forms

Comment: Yes you could generate a Fomr all in code. But styling it is much harder than  with the desigener. Maybe you want to create several UserControls and Show and Hide them with the buttons in a wizard style.. Btw: What do you mean 'with the same fields' ?

Comment: @TaW by the same fields I mean Username: [Textbox] Workstation Name: [Textbox], etc, etc

Comment: OK, if all panels are supposed to be the same, simply create more instances of your UserControl! Collect them in a `List<yourUserCOntrolClass>`..

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to create multiple forms.  You can give the user the illusion that there are multiple forms by re-using the same form and just storing the information for each form in a collection.

Create a class that would contain all the information from the form:

```
public class Information
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Workstation { get; set;}
    // ...etc
}
```

Then, simply create a collection of those objects to contain data for each screen of information

```
List<Information> list = new List<Information>();
int currentForm = 0;

private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SaveCurrentInfo();
        currentForm--;
        ClearForm();
        Information info = list[currentForm];
        txtUsername.Text = info.Username;
        txtWorkstation.Text = info.Workstation;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SaveCurrentInfo();
        currentForm++;
        ClearForm();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
private void SaveForm()
{
    Information info = new Information();
    info.Username = txtUsername.Text;
    info.Workstation = txtWorkstation.Text;
    // ...etc
    if (currentForm < list.Count)
    {
        list[currentForm] = info;
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(info);
    }
}

private void ClearForm()
{
    txtUsername.Text = string.Empty;
    txtWorkstation.Text = string.Empty;
    btnBack.Enabled = currentForm > 0;
}
```

Then you can save all the "forms" whenever you are done adding workstations.